# Change YouTube username from uppercase to lowercase

Tags: youtube

My username contains a few capital letters and I was wondering if there was a way of changing all the uppercase characters into lowercase? I know you can link it to Google+ and show my real name but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change my username on youtube?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7507/is-it-possible-to-change-my-username-on-youtube)